# System Design Interview - Car API

Tags: api-design, system-design

**System Design Question:**

You are given a dataset of a few million used cars and information about them -- miles, color, price, etc. You have to create an API endpoint in two days that allows users to query the dataset.

**This was the answer I gave:**

Use a relational database (let's say PostgreSQL) to house the data. Expose a GET endpoint that takes query string parameters corresponding to the attributes in the dataset, parses them and uses them to query the database. The endpoint can also track which attributes are queried the most and add indexes to those attributes to speed up the queries. I was asked how I would handle a range (e.g. "car with 50,000 <= miles <= 100,000") to which I said this can be handled by the query string parameter and translated into the SQL query by the GET endpoint.

**Feedback**

I was told in feedback afterwards that this answer "didn't convey a strong understanding of how to design web systems." I was hoping for some insights as to where my solution may have been insufficient/weak or may have overlooked something about designing web systems.

**Note:** I reconstructed my answer from memory so it may be clearer here than it was in the interview.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You should not construct an SQL Query directly from the URL, since this will lead to SQL-Injection, and this seems to be the point the Interviewer wanted to make using the example of the range.

Comment: @triplem why is this specific to an attribute with a range and not parameters with a single value? I see that I should have specified that I would use a stored proc, but from my research, it seems like the issue you raised would be for any parameter, right?

Comment: You are opening a whole can of worms by allowing parameters to be parsed to SQL directly. Each parameter could contain special characters and lead to some strange things on the DB (try to google for SQL Injection). and lead to data loss, or other kind of data manipulation. Even a stored procedure could be attacked by this. Therefor all parameters need to get parsed and checked.

Comment: @triplem Gotcha. So is that the solution to this issue then -- check every variable after parsing from the query string? Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like already discussed in the comments, the Interviewer wanted to hear something about SQL Injection. There are some counter measures, which you can do to avoid SQL Injection. These are (most probably not a complete list, but should give a hint, on what to look out for):

- Use Prepared Statements
- Take care about Access restrictions (in the DB as well as on the OS)
- Validate the User Input

Comment: I accepted this as the answer but wanted to add one thing -- my researched found that stored procedures are safe as well. Since they are already compiled, special characters are just treated as part of the string literals. The only danger would be in using dynamic SQL in the store procedure.